# How to prevent the automatic removing of other ajax data call functions when a data call pathway is not active on the JSON page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have the following data call pathway to a JSON API. Sometimes the data pathway is nonexistent on the API, i.e., the data pathway and associated data for this data is removed. When this happens - the whole java code is blanked out and no data is returned for previous calls within the same Ajax further up the following code. Is there any code that I can include, in the data call or otherwise, that will prevent this "blanking" of all data when the pathway is not present? Thank you.

```
                    // data call, sometimes this data is not present
                    
                    var road5f = data.tm.poi[0].cpoi[4].f;
                    var road5t = data.tm.poi[0].cpoi[4].t;
                   //
         jQuery('#road53').html(( road5f ).toString() + '    (Start)').addClass( "roadbody" );
         jQuery('#road54').html(( road5t ).toString() +  '    (Finish)').addClass( "roadbody" );
```

Html on screen

```
<span id="road53"></span><span id="road54"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have AJAX call that is similar to this :

```
$.post('requested url',function(data){

       //Data received is pages body from requested source
       //Therefore we have to check if data is not null or empty string

       if(data!=null && data!=""){
           //Rest of your JS code .......
       }
});
```

Comment: Also you should read API's doc, usually they send different response code if it fails, so you can check for that as well.

Comment: var road5f = data.tm.poi[0].cpoi[4].f;
                    if(road5f!=null && road5f!="")
                      road5r="null";

Comment: If you data == null you can not ask for its attributes like .tm.poi[0] etc. because they don't exist, you need to check if data != null.

Comment: // AJAX
jQuery.ajax ({
 url: apiUrl,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {

  console.log(data);
        
                    // report 5
                    var road5r = data.tm.poi[0].cpoi[4].r;
                    if(road5r! === undefined)
                      road5r="null";